# Wie sagt man "to do yoga" auf Deutsch?

Tags: grammar, phrase

> Ich mache schon seit 2 Jahren Yoga, um fit zu bleiben.

Kann man "Yoga machen" sagen?

Comment: A Google search for "yoga machen" produces an answer to this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can,
Ich mache schon seit 2 Jahren Yoga.

Other example:
Ich mache schon seit 2 Jahren Sport.

and so on.

Comment: Danke! Ich vertraue der Online-Übersetzung nicht, da sie alles wörtlich übersetzt.

Comment: @DerPolyglott33 Wörtlich wäre "machen" aber "make" ;) Daher sagen deutsche so gerne "I make my homework", was ja bekanntlich falsch ist.

Comment: Stimmt, aber: Ich spiele schon seit 2 Jahren Fußball.